# Show $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{24}$ by looking at their centers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Every proof seems to use an argument that looks at the orders and finds an element with a certain order in $S_4$ and no element in $D_{24}$ has that order...

Wouldn't it be much much easier to look at the centers? The center of $S_4$ is just $\{e\}$ but the center of $D_{24}$ has two elements in it... thus an isomorphism cannot exist.

Comment: That works.$\;$

Comment: Sammy Black- thank you for your swift response. I think the technique of exhibiting an element in $S_n$ with a certain order, whose counterpart (with that order) does not exist in $D_n$  is more general and useful, because $D_n$ can have one element in the center when $n/2$ is odd...

Answer (score 3):

(Just so this question has an answer.)

That is of course a valid proof. Whether it would be easier is debatable. Showing the center of $D_{24}$ contains two elements isn't too bad as there is a standard generating set with simple relations. I don't know how easy it is to show that $S_4$ has trivial center. Furthermore, the definition of order of an element is usually presented earlier than the definition of the center of a group, so the proofs you've seen may be considered more elementary.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Vandal: Just a another possible reason why this style of proof might be preferable: if you happen to prove that $D_{24}$ is not isomorphic to $S_{4}$ by showing that $D_{24}$ has an element of order $6$, and $S_{4}$ does not, you can in fact show that any group of order $24$ with an element of order $6$ cannot be isomorphic to $S_{4}$. The proof you mention, of course, is much more specific, and only shows that $D_{24}$ and $S_{4}$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Proof for the triviality of the center of $S_4$: the conjugate $gag^{-1}$ of $a$ is just a relabeling of $a$. For example, if $a=(123)$, then $gag^{-1}=(g(1)g(2)g(3))$. It's not hard to show that if $a\neq 1$, the identity, then the conjugate class of $a$ isn't a singleton.

Comment: @FrankScience, you are of course proving that all $S_n$, for $n \ge 3$, are centerless.